# I need to check if certain number is in string of numbers

Tags: php, regex, explode, stripos

I really need some help with this... i just cant make it work.

For now i have this piece of code and it's working fine.
What it does is... retuns all files within a directory according to date in their name.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$imagesDir = '';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$filteredImages = [];
foreach($images as $image) {
    $current_date = date("Ymd");
    $file_date = substr($image, 0, 8);
    if (strcmp($current_date, $file_date)>=0)
        $filteredImages[] = $image;
}
echo json_encode($filteredImages, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

But now i need to filter those files (probably before this code is even executed). acording to the string in their name.

files are named in the following manner:

```
yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.123456789.jpg
yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.9.jpg
yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.458.jpg
```

i need to filter out only ones that have certain number within that string of numbers at the end (between `"."`  and `".jpg"`)   eg. number `9`

```
$number = 9
```

i was trying with this piece of code to seperate only that last part of name:

```
<?php
function getBetween($jpgname,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $jpgname);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}

$jpgname = "yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.12789.jpg";
$start = ".";
$end = ".jpg";
$output = getBetween($jpgname,$start,$end);
echo $output;
?>
```

and i guess i would need STRIPOS within all of this... but im lost now...  :(

Comment: I see you edited your code. Is it a file name with a single digit you want or a file name with a specific name, that happens to be a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use preg_grep.
It's regex for arrays.

This is untested but I think it should work.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$imagesDir = '';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$find = 9;
$filtered = preg_grep("/.*?\.\d*" . $find . "\d*\./", $images);
```

The regex will look for anything to a dot then any number or no number, the $find then any or no number again and a dot again.

Comment: lets say i have $number = 9  how to set $number in that filtered part?

Comment: So that is what you are looking for, a specific number. So you want a variable `$find` that you set and you want to get only the file name matching? Or do you also want "19"?

Comment: it will be allways only one digit number.

Comment: uff.. i dont know how to post code in here...  :(
i get empty echo

Comment: ok... this works only if theres single digit at the end a
fails if there are more digits  :(

Comment: But you said just a few minutes ago *it will be allways only one digit number.* Now you say it fail when it's  more digits. Seriously?!!!

Comment: i will allways search for only one digit amongst string of digits. that string can be long from minimum one to maximum nine digits.

Comment: thats it... is there a way to get result in same form as entry $images is?
["yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.123456789.jpg", "yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.9.jpg"]

Comment: They are the same form.

Comment: if result is single name than it is ... but if result is multiple then it looks like this:
{"0":"20180517_xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx~20180530.123456789.jpg","2":"20180519_xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx~20180530.9.jpg"}

Comment: Yes, that is how an array works. You need to read about arrays. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Ok, this was very helpfull. now i just need to figure out how to get clear responce.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need ? It will give you 123456789

```
$string = "yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.123456789.jpg";

$explode = explode(".", $string);

echo ($explode[1]);
```

Edit -

As per your requirement Andreas's solution seems to be working.

This is what I tried , I changed the find variable and checked.

```
$images = array("yyyymmdd_xxxxxxx-xxxxxx~yyyymmdd.12789.jpg");

$find = 32;
$filtered = preg_grep("/.*?." . $find . "./", $images);

print_r($filtered);
```

Comment: i have reched this step with mine code (although this looks far more elegant :) ) but i dont know how to further proceed with filtering.

Comment: What is the condition which decides which filepath you need and dont need? Is it a specific number of something like that ?

Comment: first part of my code filters files by date and that works ok.
now i need to filter that further... and i am stuck there.
lets say i have $number = 9   i need all files that have number 9 in that last part

Comment: So if you get a string like 552 in the middle. Now if your number is 2 or 52 or 552 then this is valid ? am i right?

Comment: i will allways search for only one digit amongst string of digits. that string can be long from minimum one to maximum nine digits.

Comment: So the position of the number does not matter? Any digit in the string must have $number as a subset ?

Comment: Why are you using my code in your answer? Also, you obviously don't know regex well enough to answer with regex.