# how to adjust my array output

Tags: php, arrays

Ouch... i just cant get it... 
online i can set things right:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/492fa3050bf906b4a6c0631bdb66b7f066f23034
but on my live server its not working...  :(

help needed.

if my array has single item than my responce looks like this:

```
["20180517_xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx~20180530.123456789.jpg"]
```

and thats ok with me.

but if my array has more then one file, responce then looks like this:

```
{"0":"20180517_xxxxxx-xxxxx~20180530.123456789.jpg","2":"20180519_xxxx-xxxxx~20180530.1.jpg"}
```

**how do i adjust my responce to be as first one?**

```
["20180517_xxxxxx-xxxxxx~20180530.123456789.jpg","20180519_xxxxx-xxxxx~20180530.1.jpg"]
```

thanx!

sorry... heres my code:

more details here: [I need to check if certain number is in string of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493091/i-need-to-check-if-certain-number-is-in-string-of-numbers/50493180?noredirect=1#comment88004277_50493180)

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$imagesDir = '';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$find = 1;
//$filtered = preg_grep("/.*?\." . $find . "\./", $images);

$filteredImages = [];
foreach($images as $image) {
    $current_date = date("Ymd");
    $file_date = substr($image, 0, 8);
    if (strcmp($current_date, $file_date)>=0)
        $filteredImages[] = $image;
}
//$result = [];
$filtered = preg_grep("/.*?\.\d*" . $find . "\d*\./", $filteredImages);
//var_dump($filtered);
$result = $filtered;

echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Comment: How does the code look in the code? how does it differ from the code in the sandbox? Putting the code directly in the question can help us greatly in helping you solve your problem.

Comment: So you didn't read about arrays? I told you to read about arrays. Again, it's the same thing.

Comment: @Andreas  
yes and iw made piece of code that worked ok online ... but on my server its different .
I am not that strong in PHP so i am looking for help here...  :(

Comment: Still, you had to read nine examples from php.net to get your answer. what is that in time? 15-20 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` will only encode an array using JSON array syntax if the indexes are sequential integers starting from `0`. Otherwise it's encoded using object syntax, with the indexes as explicit keys.

When you use `array_filter`, the elements that are retained keep their same indexes from the original. If you filter out elements `1` and `3` from the array, you get indexes `0` and `2`, so it's encoded as an object.

You can use `array_values()` to get an array with sequential indexes:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```